# Rspec Test Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec2

Ruby 1.9.2, RoR 3.0.1. When I run 'rspec spec' I get this error. Can't really make sense of it.

```
connor@connor-desktop:~/rubystore$ rspec spec
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:20:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant Admins (NameError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-expectations-2.0.1/lib/rspec/expectations/backward_compatibility.rb:6:in `const_missing'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.1.3/app/controllers/devise/admins_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `block in eager_load!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:11:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:11:in `all'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:107:in `eager_load!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
from /home/connor/rubystore/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from /home/connor/rubystore/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from /home/connor/rubystore/spec/controllers/products_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:306:in `load'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:306:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:306:in `map'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:306:in `load_spec_files'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

Anybody have an idea of what may be going on?

Comment: seems a problem with your devise configuration. Your application works ? You can run it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from /home/connor/rubystore/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/connor/rubystore/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/connor/rubystore/spec/controllers/products_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Check these lines for errors. Or maybe something is to be included in your spec_helper.rb file